Computing channel capacity for channels types other than simple AWGN
My question is about computing capacity for comms channel models other than simple AWGN. For example, a very simple multipath channel (say line-of-sight + one path) plus AWGN.
Are there any such non-AWGN channels with an analytical solution for capacity along the lines of the famous Shannon formula for the AWGN channel? If not that, perhaps even being able to establish some upper/lower bounds on channel capacity? I have done work with multipath + AWGN as a student, but the evaluation was always done via simulation.
A related question is whether, when you have a channel with strong multipath, that any analysis based on an AWGN channel is unlikely to provide any useful information, even bounds. So you don't bother with than and just to do simulations.
